# LibreOffice how to recup the current element

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-basic, openoffice-impress

I want to retrieve the current element in LibreOffice Impress to apply changes to it.

For example, I'm trying to retrieve this shape to change the text in it with macros.

[image: image of rectangle with text "Recup this shape"]

I tried to find information with the X-ray tool but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the currently selected shape:

```
oSel = ThisComponent.getCurrentController.getSelection()
oShape = oSel.getByIndex(0)
Print oShape.getString()
```

To iterate through all shapes in the slide, start with `ThisComponent.getDrawPages()` and then use *XrayTool*.

You may also find the following snippet of python code helpful:

```
def iterate_draw_shapes():
    oDrawPage = oDrawPages.getByIndex(1)
    for oShape in oDrawPage:
        if oShape.supportsService("com.sun.star.drawing.TextShape"):
            oTexts = oShape.createEnumeration()
            while oTexts.hasMoreElements():
                oText = oTexts.nextElement()
                oTextPortions = oText.createEnumeration()
                while oTextPortions.hasMoreElements():
                    oTextPortion = oTextPortions.nextElement()
```